# Trigger Submit button with Enter Key React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to press the Enter Key and send a message. I try this:

But there is an error.

```
<input type="text" className="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..."
                        onChange={this.handleTextChange} value={this.state.newMessage}
                    />
<span className="input-group-btn">
<input type="submit" value="Send" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onSubmit={this.handleSendMessage}                       
                    /></span>
```

And I want to manage my function:

```
handleSendMessage = e => {}
```

I already try OnKeyPressed but I can't call my functions there.
Thank you.

I prefer a solution without jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would add a keyPress event on the input text input and then detect for an enter key press using `e.which ===13`

```
onKeyPress = (e) => {
    if(e.which === 13) {
      this.handleSendMessage();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div style={styles}>
      <input type="text" className="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..."
        onChange={this.handleTextChange} onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress} value={this.state.newMessage}
      />
      <span className="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onSubmit={this.handleSendMessage}
        /></span>
  </div>
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `form` for it and change your button type to `submit`

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSendMessage}>
  <input type="text" className="form-control input-sm chat_input"
    placeholder="Write your message here..."
    onChange={this.handleTextChange} value={this.state.newMessage}
  />
  <span className="input-group-btn">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/>
  </span>
</form>
```